# Is there an existing filtering method to use in IoT Gateways and what are the characteristics that can be used when filtering data?

Tags: device, sensors, iot, gateway

I know that an IoT gateway must filter data coming from different devices/sensors, but I can't find how the process is done.

I think that timestamp can be a characteristic that may help us when  developing the filtering process but is there others.

Added to that is there an algorithm that let me identifying different devices, I know that every device has a unique ID (some of them use 6 bytes as an identifier others 5 bytes ...) but I want to identify my devices in a standard way .

Comment: Which gateway in particular are you thinking of, and which protocol will be used to send the data?

Comment: I am trying to implement Bluetooth low energy / MQTT gateway . The gateway collect data from devices , filter , store them if necessary (a queue) , translate protocols and publish them to the server ( where there exist an mqtt broker)

Comment: With MQTT, surely you know which device is sending because you simply publish to a device-specific topic? [This HiveMQ article has tips for naming topics so that you know the source](http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-5-mqtt-topics-best-practices); is that what you're asking for?

Comment: No, for devices i can communicate with them using BLE

Comment: before translating protocols i have to filter and manage incoming data

Comment: The devices on the edge usually have resource constraints and run RTOS, I don't think there "one size fits all" type of filtering mechanism, hence filter is very specific need based on requirements.

Comment: the devices are an intelligence ,they advertise themselves when having new data  but the gateway will schedule the act of connection and transmitting data . by the way in my case there is no hard real time constraint but if you want we can talk about soft real time which can be managed using an optimised scheduling algorithm.